# How to get a question answered

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I have posted a question once and did not get any answer. So how do I make people to see the question. It seems to me that the question goes down in the list so no one checks it. So is there some way to keep it on the top so that more people notice it. And also how can I request some specific person for an answer.  For example in one of my question's a person posted try asking Asaf Karagila. So how do I do that?

Comment: The standard way of attracting more attention to a question is to [offer a bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/214632).  Note, however, that a question must be at least two days old before a bounty can be offered on it, meaning that the last three questions you have posed are not eligible, yet. There is no way to guarantee that a particular user will see/be interested in/answer your questions, and some users do not react well to being asked to look at specific questions by their posers.

Comment: I actually think the best way to attract people to answer your questions is to learn to ask questions well.

Comment: Try asking who?

Comment: By the way, I went through all of your 12 questions, and none of them had that "try asking Asaf" that you mention. Not even the one question that I answered.

Comment: Are you going to respond to any of the comments?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I do not remember exactly which question had it but I have definitely remember seeing it. But I remember that it was a set theory question.

Comment: Maybe [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696043/why-there-is-not-the-next-real-number/696047#comment1458354_696047)?

Comment: @AsafKaragila yes in that comment

Comment: Well, (1) not everyone is reading every comment. (2) For that particular comment, I think that the answer has been discussed on the site before, several times. (3) I will probably be away from writing actual answers until tomorrow evening (roughly 24 hours from now). (4) What Willie said.

Answer (score 6):

> For example in one of my question's a person posted try asking Asaf Karagila. So how do I do that?

Three simple steps:

1. Ask a question. (Not in a comment, not as an answer, but as a question.)
2. Tag it with some combination of [elementary-set-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-set-theory) or [set-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set-theory) with other things. The difference between those two tags are sometimes mystical and esoteric, and Asaf may chew you out for using the wrong one, but at least you will have gotten his attention.
3. Wait. (I have it on good authority that [Asaf rarely sleeps](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13048/is-the-enthusiast-badge-internationally-fair#comment51159_13048) and probably personally reviews all questions in [those two tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/215/set-theory).)

If you are more statistically inclined, I would suggest looking at [Asaf's user history](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/622/asaf-karagila) to figure out the most opportune times (day of the week, hours of the day) to ensure rapid engagement.

---

But in all seriousness: if you don't feel that your question has been sufficiently seen or answered, [we have a help center item for that](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers).

Comment: Well, if you're going to use site activity to find a good time to track down a user, there's a [data.SE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/102172/distribution-of-user-activity-per-hour) for that!  (Asaf's UserID is 622.)

Comment: For most opportune times: just avoid St. Patrick's Day and it should be fine. ;-)

Comment: "Asaf rarely sleeps" It seems highly time to start a list of [Asaf's facts](http://www.chucknorrisfacts.com/).

Comment: @Did: [MSO did one for Jon Skeet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts), but he was (and still is) the highest rep user there by quite a margin. Asaf facts would just not be the same without him dominating us with his reputation score.

Comment: @Did: I'm amused by the idea; but I'd feel really bad if it would become reality.

Comment: @WillieWong Asaf does not even need to be the highest rep user to be Asaf. Ergo, $\text{Asaf}\gg\text{Jon Skeet}$.

Comment: @Asaf Sorry, it seems I started the list.